# How can I separate a passed text area into an array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a text area of words which is separated by lines passed to my PHP page and I want to separate the words into an array and then print each word on a new line.

How do I do this? Is the following code right? It doesn't seem to work!

```
<?php
    $words = $_POST["words"];
    $arr = explode("\n",$words);
?>
```

Comment: You want to explode the content of your textarea word by word or line by line?

Comment: You sure there are line breaks there? Normal people don't hit enter between words, even if the instructions say so. Maybe try exploding on whitespace and commas, too.

Comment: @ChrisHenry Thanks for that. The idea is words are on a separate line after instruction on pressing enter, but following the answers below I still can't get it working. How would I separate on both comma and whitespace so it would separate words together like "one, two".